# How to make scale_manual apply colors without drawing the plot when used in loops?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was trying to produce a list of ggplots for a list of data frames where each plot should use a different color palett which I tried to achieve with scale_fill_manual. However, the last color was applied to all plots. I eventually found out, that it only works if I draw each plot before append it to the list...

Here is a minimal example:

```
# no extra plotting
df <- split(mtcars, mtcars$gear)
colours <- c("red", "green", "blue")

plots <- list()
for(i in 1:length(df)){
   .plot <- ggplot(df[[i]], aes(x=as.factor(carb), fill=as.factor(gear))) + geom_bar() +
   scale_fill_manual(values=colours[[i]])

   plots[[length(plots)+1]] <- .plot
}

plot1 <- arrangeGrob(grobs=plots)
```

In the output, all bars are blue.

```
#second version:
plots2 <- list()
for(i in 1:length(df)){
  .plot2 <- ggplot(df[[i]], aes(x=as.factor(carb), fill=as.factor(gear))) + geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=colours[[i]])

  #the magic trick
  grid.draw(.plot2)
  plots2[[length(plots2)+1]] <- .plot2
}

plot2 <- arrangeGrob(grobs=plots2)
```

Now it works properly. Is there any other way to make it work? In my case, plotting each subplot would take really long.

(If this is a bug, it is a really weird one... It worked in debug mode, and when I manually executed each line of the loop. Took a long time to notice that it is because I drew the plots in each loop...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better option would be

```
df <- split(mtcars, mtcars$gear)
colours <- c("red", "green", "blue")

plots <- lapply(1:length(df), function(i) {
   .plot <- ggplot(df[[i]], aes(x=as.factor(carb), fill=as.factor(gear))) + 
       geom_bar() +
       scale_fill_manual(values=colours[[i]])
   .plot
})
```

here we replace the `for` loop with `lapply`. This avoids the problem of the lazy evaluation of parameters and the fact that the value of `i` isn't captured inside a for loop the way it is with `sapply/lapply`. Essentially the problem was that all plots were tied to the value of `i` when you plotted them, not the value of `i` when they were created. This method essentially creates closures so each plot has its own value of `i`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the problem lies in lazy evaluation, and for this very elegant and beautiful solution! Thanks! - Goodbye loops

Comment: For future readers: adding `ggplotGrob(.plot)` to the list instead of `.plot` also solves the problem